# How can I get all child categories - of a child category based on url segment?

Tags: categories, segments

I am missing something very obvious I think. I am trying to get all child categories based on url segment.

For example: "mysite.com/foo"

I have a category Group called `Sections` Within `Sections` I have a category called `Foo`.

**Categories**:

```
Sections  <-- Category Group
    |- Foo
        |- One
        |- Two
        |- Three
```

Using this url as an example: `www.mysite.com/foo`

**twig**

```
{% set categoryGroup = craft.categories.group('Sections').level(1).slug(craft.request.getSegment(1)).first() %}
{% set categories = craft.categories.ancestorOf(categoryGroup) %}
```

Doing this: `<p>Group: {{ categoryGroup }}</p>`

Renders this: `Group: Foo`

Great!

```
{% if categories|length %}
    {% for cat in categories %}
        {{ cat.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    NOTHING
{% endif %}
```

I am always getting back my `NOTHING` statement. When I navigate to `mysite.com/foo`, I would like to show `One Two Three`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things I would do differently here. The first is to check the **Categories in this group have their own URLs** box in the Category Group settings. Set the url to `{slug}`, and you will have `category` defined in the template without needing:

> `{% set categoryGroup = craft.categories.group('Sections')
>   .level(1)
>   .slug(craft.request.getSegment(1))
>   .first() %}`

The second problem is that once you have your [category](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/categorymodel), what you want are the [children](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/categorymodel#getChildren), not the [ancestors](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/categorymodel#getAncestors):

```
{% set theChildren = category.children %}

{% if theChildren|length %}
  {% for cat in theChildren %}
    {{ cat.title }}
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  NOTHING
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Worked great - once again I was over-complicating things. Thank you!